# How to make Vine leaves twirling around a branch

Tags: modeling

Im trying to make leaves go around a spiral (making it look like a branch).
I am using instancing, parenting it to the branch. The leaves are going into the same direction. How can I give the leaves randomness?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should use Particles > Hair instead?

Comment: Spotted a tutorial on YT! Thanks again!